# Utilizar flexbox Grid o position

Tags: html, css, web

A la hora de maquetar html utilizo position y float. Mis dudas surgen a la hora de empezar con flex y grid, cuándo debo de empezar a utilizar estos valores y qué diferencia hay entre ellos?

Comment: Yo como programador siempre uso Flexbox cuando requiero usar una de sus ventajas que ofrece; centrar verticalmente, columnas, botones, etc.. Position uso cuando hago un menú flotante y float muy poco, solo cuando agrego imagenes dentro de textos

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las dos maneras son buenas y es algo de preferencia, y cada dev va a tener su propia opinión.

Flexbox es más fácil que grid. Puedes estudiar Flexbox en [Flexbox Froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/), un juego divertido para aprender flexbox.   El concepto es que hay 2 ejes: el eje principal, y el eje transversal, y todas las propiedades están en contexto con ellos.

Una de las cosas que no me gustó de CSS Grid es que si tienes que cambiar algo, sea añadir o borrar una cuadra, tienes que cambiar la disposición entera (layout), cada fila y columna. No es escalable para diseños complejos que suelen cambiar.

También, flexbox tiene más soporte en las navegadoras porque es más viejo.

Yo enseñaba un programa de bootcamp, y te recomiendo que empieces con flexbox por la razón que es más fácil aprender.

Con respecto a "position," no es una alternativa a grid o flexbox, sino otra herramienta que puedes usar. Position es útil cuando tienes que poner elementos que no tienen relación con otros, o que tienen que suponerse encima de otros elementos, por ejemplo, hamburger menu icon, flechas para carousels, sticky headers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno pues estos dos métodos son bastante utilizados valla, y son muy buenos aunque no son parecidos.

aquí te dejo un par de referencias que podrías consultar:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout

https://platzi.com/blog/flexbox-vs-css-grid-cual-es-la-diferencia/

Ahora bien, yo te quiero explicar también un poco sobre estos dos, para mi pienso que la principal diferencia entre estos dos son los ejes que manejan, dado que flexbox utiliza **un solo eje, ya sea vertical u horizontal**, luego por el lado de grid podemos ver que maneja **dos ejes**, permitiendote maquetar de mejor manera un sitio web.

### Cuando utilizar cada una:

Pues en mi opinión esto depende bastante del caso, una opción típica y básica de grid, es cuando tienes una cuadricula en donde quieres imprimir ya sea tarjetas, publicaciones o lo que sea, parecido a esta imagen:
[image: Imagen de ejemplo de grid]

Como puedes ver, eso es lo fantastico de grid, te permite maquetar no sólo uniformemente sino que si tu quieres, la primera tarjeta puede tener más ancho o largo que las demás manejando las [lineas del grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Grid_Lines).

En conclusión pensaría que es bueno utilizar grid para maquetar el layout general, y luego en el caso de flexbox lo podrías utilizar en las tarjetas por ejemplo (siguiendo el ejemplo de la imagen anterior), y de esa manera al juntar los dos se consiguen resultados geniales.

### Ventajas:

También quiero poner las principales ventajas que me han servido de los dos a lo largo del tiempo que llevo programando.

Por el lado de grid, me encanta el super manejo que tienes del flujo de la página, te permite poscicionar las cosas casi que donde quieras, y te permite maquetar tu web de manera bastante profesional

Por el lado de flexbox, me parece que lo genial es su innegable capacidad para de centrar como tu quieras las cosas, con sus [diferentes propiedades](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/propiedades-contenedor-flexbox.html), que la verdad que todas son bastante útiles y diversas.